# Blender rendering repeating same frame over and over

Tags: rendering

When I started rendering an animation it kept using 1 frame for every frame and sometimes it renders blank as well. I am rendering on cycles, but it is also rendering instantly and when I put it on eevee it goes on cycles quality.

Comment: "it kept using 1 frame for every frame" is unclear.

Comment: I meant the same frame was repeated for every frame when rendering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is because you have an image sequence/single image in the video editing tab of Blender. Simply delete this strip, and your animation should render correctly.

This would explain the black frames, repeated frames, instant renders, and cycles-quality renders when set on EEVEE.

Comment: I guess I did have an image there. Seems to be working fine now. Thx.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as to help future users

Comment: THANK YOU
The Editing Mode would have been the last thing i thougt of, trying to find the problem with my render settings...
This is such a vital information and I searched so long for this answer >-<
This is definetly something for the "fix" suggestions for future blender versions.