# Changing render image dimensions seems to change borders around a fixed image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, dimensions

I'm working on a scene and had run some test renders at 1920x1080. After some more work, I tried to render at 3840x2160 and I am seeing a transparency box around an otherwise 1080p image:

[image: Screenshot of described issue]

I'm also noticing that when I scale it down to something like 1280x720, it is a crop of that image. It seems that Blender is just drawing a box of the specified dimensions around a fixed image.

Any ideas what I might have done to cause this?

Comment: Since the question was posted, I'm also seeing that if I go to an earlier frame and render it (when the camera is animated to a completely different place and angle), it still gives me the same image.

Comment: Solved. In light of some additional (even more confusing) symptoms, I was able to find this post which solved the problem: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195065/blender-rendering-repeating-same-frame-over-and-over